# Vite failing to load config

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, vite

I am working on a web application that uses Vite alongside Django and I am unabnle to get my dev server to run at all.

I am really not sure what all information I need to post as I'm brand new to JavaScript but below is the error code and then my vite.config.js. I could not find any helpful information by just looking up the error message.

```
failed to load config from C:\Users\vinny\OneDrive\Documents\CS49999\ct-scheduling\vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: File
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vinny\OneDrive\Documents\CS49999\ct-scheduling\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vinny\OneDrive\Documents\CS49999\ct-scheduling\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\helpers\config-api.js:16:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
```

'vite.config.js'

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  
  build: {
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: './src/main.jsx',
    },
  },
  
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
          target: 'http://USERNAME.pythonanywhere.com',
          changeOrigin: true,
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What's strange is that this exact config works on one PC and not another.

I ran the command `npm run dev` expecting to see my server start up so I could take a look at how the website is actually displaying. Instead I am met with the above error.

I have reinstalled node twice now so I am confident that is not the issue.
Any information will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which version of nodejs is installed on the machines? There is an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25782) with nodejs 20.6 for angular and I saw the same issue for Vite.

Comment: if your config works on another PC, then it's most likely the npm/node.js version on the PC with the issue. Maybe use the same version installed on the other PC

Comment: The PC that isn't working is running node 20.6.0 while the working one is running 20.5.1.
I can't find an install for 20.5.1 on the node website and doing it in the command line does not yield a different version of node than 20.6.0.

Comment: Well I guess you have the answer on your question now. I'd recommend to start using `node version manager` for painless nodejs versions switching. Or just use LTS version of Nodejs.